# Android in app billing check is product published or unpublished

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

Is there any way to check is product published or unpublished? 
To do not display SKU which is unpublished.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your app has been published, when you add in-app purchases and save it, it should auto-update your already-published app.

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand that, but what if I've published in-app product, and then in Google Play Developer Console I'm deactivating product, there is switcher in product details screen, in that case I will receive SKU details, but if user will push button buy - google play will return error - because of product will be unavailable. So for that situation for deactivated products, I want hide deactivated products.